# Cannot connect to AWS RDS from Docker Container inside an ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-rds, amazon-ecs

I deployed a docker container inside of an ECS cluster, and I am not able to connect to my Postgres RDS instance.

Notes:

- My ECS cluster instance and my RDS instance are in the same VPC.
- My ECS cluster and my docker container's `/etc/resolve.conf` files are identical. I can telnet to my RDS instance from within the ECS cluster shell, but not from within the docker container.
- When I run the docker container on my local machine, it can connect to the Postgres RDS instance.
- My RDS security group is allowing all inbound traffic (for now).

More notes:

- When I telnet from inside the docker container (using `telnet my-database.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com 5432` to my RDS instance, I get the following error:

  `Connection closed by foreign host`
- For the time being, I am allowing all ports in my ACL.

So the question is, how do I connect to AWS RDS from a Docker Container that is inside of an ECS cluster?

Comment: Are you seeing any connection errors?  Can you post logs here?

Comment: Can you once re check the network ACL's of your subnets inside VPC?

Comment: @Anuruddha I posted my connection error.

Comment: @VineethGuna I am allowing all ports in my ACL in the VPC subnets.

Comment: @AlexPan Can you share screen shots of security groups ingress rules for RDS instance and your ECS? Is your deployment similar to this scenario? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html#USER_VPC.Scenario1

Comment: @AlexPan Were you able to resolve this issue ? I am facing same issue, RDS is accessible from ECS host but not from inside the container.